# How would grub2 be affected when deleting the main OS?

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, elementary

So I was wondering what would happen to grub2 if someone uses several OSes on the same computer and then deletes one of them?

For instance I installed Elementary OS and Ubuntu 16.04 and now the computer uses the grub2 that Elementary OS installed.

What would happen if I decided to delete Elementary OS and keep using my computer with only Ubuntu?

Would there be errors while booting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since grub's config file is usually stored in the /boot folder of the OS that installed it, deleting that OS would cause grub to fall into rescue mode. It can easily be repaired though.

The best method to avoid problems, is to boot an OS that you are keeping. Reinstall grub from that OS. Then, delete the OS you are removing and update grub.

Comment: So simply reinstalling grub from the os I'm planning to keep before doing any deletions is the answer? I'll keep that in mind. You literally save me from big hassle.

Comment: yes, because reinstalling will make grub look for its config in the OS that installed it.